# ¿Cómo implementar bien el método abstracto?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase `CAnimal`, donde guardo el nombre, la edad y el sonido. Tengo en esta misma el método abstracto `public abstract void sonido(String cate);`
donde meto el sonido que hace al meter "perro" o "gato"(por práctica).
En la clase heredada `CCategoria` tengo el `String categoria` donde se asigna si es perro o gato. En la clase `CCategoria` el método abstracto lo tengo definido así:

```
@Override
public void sonido(String cate){
        if(cate.equalsIgnoreCase("gato")){
            asignarSonido("miau");
        }
        else if(cate.equalsIgnoreCase("perro")){
            asignarSonido("guau");
        }
    }
```

Y en el constructor de esta clase tengo:

```
public CCategoria(String nombre, int edad, String categoria){
        super(nombre, edad);
        asignarCategoria(categoria);
        sonido(categoria);
    }
```

Mi duda, ¿estoy haciendo bien esto? estoy en esta parte ahora, pero no logro entender bien su funcionamiento. Si no es la forma idónea de ocupar los métodos abstractos, ¿como podría utilizarlo de forma correcta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu ejemplo tanto Perro como Gato son clases especializadas de la clase abstracta Animal, una clase abstracta debes verla como un Type genérico o base a partir del cual crearas clases mas especializadas, las clases abstractas a diferencia de una interfaz (a partir de Java 8 una interfaz puede proporcionar la implementación a través de métodos default) permiten definir la implementación de los métodos a excepción de los métodos que declares explícitamente como métodos abstract, en este caso declaras al metodo sonido en la clase Animal como abstract ya que cada clase especializada de Animal debe proporcionar la implementación, entonces definimos la clase abstracta AbstractAnimal, fijate que al declarar como abstract el método 'sonido', este no define la implementación del método, de hecho ni siquiera declara el bloque de código.

```
public abstract class AbstractAnimal {
    public abstract void sonido();
}
```

Al implementar las clases mas especializadas de AbstractAnimal, estas forzado a proporcionar la implementación del método 'sonido', es aquí donde diferencias entre el sonido que haria la clase especializada Perro y la clase especializada Gato.

```
public class Perro extends AbstractAnimal {
    @Override
    public void sonido() {
        System.out.println("Guau!");
    }
}

public class Gato extends AbstractAnimal {
    @Override
    public void sonido() {
        System.out.println("Miau!");
    }
}
```

Puedes instanciar tanto Perro como Gato de la siguiente manera

```
AbstractAnimal perroFirulais = new Perro();
AbstractAnimal gatoRamon = new Gato();

perroFirulais.sonido(); // imprimira 'Guau!'
gatoRamon.sonido(); // imprimira 'Miau!'
```

También fíjate que el type tanto para perroFirulais como para gatoRamon utilizo la misma clase AbstractAnimal a pesar de que los valores son instancias diferentes una instancia de Perro y una instancia de Gato a esta propiedad se la conoce como polimorfismo.

Una corrección es que a partir de Java 8 introdujeron los métodos Default en las interfaces, con ellos una interfaz puede proveer la implementación default de los métodos, esto lo hicieran principalmente por la introducción de lambdas (programación funcional) al querer integrar estos con los API's ya existentes como Collection y List sin romper la implementación existente de estos API's en versiones anteriores, pero toma en cuenta que esto es solo desde la versión de Java 8 en adelante.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Sólo quisiera añadir que en las interfaces también se pueden definir metodos con `default`, no sólo declararlos como pareces indicar en tu primer parrafo. Sería mejor que editaras la respuesta cambiando esto.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n gracias por tu corrección, ya fue editado.

Comment: una duda @CarlosLucero, ¿al ser Void no causaría error? ¿se debe cambiar a String para que me devuelva el mensaje?

Comment: @JoseLuis no hay error ya que el método no retorna ningún valor, en el ejemplo el método sonido solamente imprime en pantalla una cadena si te fijas en ninguna declaración del método hay un 'return' por lo tanto es valido, si quieres que en lugar de imprimir 'Guau!' o 'Miau!' te devuelva el valor entonces debes modificar el método para que devuelva dicho valor en ese caso si cambias void por String pero dentro del método debes retornar el valor, return "Guau!"; y return "Miau!" respectivamente

Comment: @CarlosLucero entiendo, ¿sería válido hacer algo como Perro extends Gato? lo intenté y funcionó, ¿haciendo esto se pierde alguna propiedad o velocidad en la ejecución?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas.

Los métodos abstractos no se implementan en la misma clase,esto se hace en las clases que le heredan.
Además debes recordar que las clases que tienen métodos abstractos deben ser declaradas como abstractas de igual forma.